# Where does Android Studio's Layout Editor store Favorite Attribute info?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

The Android Studio Graphical Layout Editor lets the user designate one or more of a View's attributes as a "Favorite Attribute" by clicking a star in the properties panel on the right:

[image]

[image]

It might be nice to be able to share the favorite attributes with other programmers via a source controlled file. Where does Android Studio store this list of favorite attributes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `~/.AndroidStudio2.3/config/options.xml` and look for the `ANDROID.STARRED.PROPERTIES` `<property>` element.

Note that:

- You would need to adjust the directory based on the Android Studio version (and find where this is really located if you are running Windows)
- This is totally undocumented and so may vary between Android Studio versions
- This is based on ~45 seconds' experimentation

Comment: thanks for finding that. interesting that it's a global setting and not local to each project or each layout file. on my windows machine, the property ANDROID.STARRED_PROPERTIES is found under my user directory in the file: .AndroidStudio2.3\config\options\options.xml

Comment: and on my Mac the file is: ~/Library/Preferences/AndroidStudio2.3/options/options.xml